# Dead Kernel while working on jupyter notebook in Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, kernel, google-cloud-datalab

I have been working on a GCP for one of my current projects and I occasionally use Datalab for writing snippets of data wrangling/processing codes. I have succesfully set up my project and VM and have established a connection to datalab from my cloud shell, but when I am trying to create a new jupyter notebook I am facing an error saying "Not Found".
I am even unable to edit my existing notebooks as all the notebooks have a dead kernel (a time bomb comes up) which are also not giving me an option to restart the kernel. I have tried re-establishing the datalab connection multiple times but that does not seem to work. My teammates who use the same instance for other project work are facing similar issues. Kindly help.

Thank you

Comment: Your question needs more clarifications. For instance, did you change your port to Port 8081 as indicated here https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/working-with-notebooks#source_control.

Comment: Hi Ismail, I did change my port to 8081 and performed all the steps while setting up my datalab instance from an active cloud shell. Still the kernel of the notebooks is dead and I am even unable to create new notebooks in datalab. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Datalab instances are [single-user only](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/datalab-team#create_instances_for_each_team_member). If multiple people try to use the same instance, then things can randomly break.

If each team member is a project [editor](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/datalab-team#each_team_member_creates_their_own_instance), each can create their own Cloud Datalab instances.

Alternatively, you can share an email address among multiple people.